# SSL connection for RTSP video streaming

Tags: android, ssl

How to establish a secure connection for rtsp video streaming and how to establish a handshake with client and server? How to install the ssl certificate in the android application. We have the .pem format ssl certification which is not supported in android and how to convert the .pem to android supported format?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5951605/3831557) for https and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20737785/3831557) for rtsp video streaming.

Comment: how to play rtsp url video using ssl socket.

Comment: Is certificate authentication need for ssl socket creation in client side?